# Using CSS @Font-Face / Google Fonts gives different sizes for numbers and letters

Tags: css, google-font-api

The following code produces the text `Hello 7432832 KB` but the size of the letters is larger than the size of the digits by a few pixels. Yet in [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro) it appears well and in the same size...

[image]

Here's the code:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
    
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
```

```html
<body>Hello 7432832 KB</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing for both examples given. The numbers **are** slightly shorter than the tallest letters. If you open your image in an image editor like Photoshop and place a ruler along the top of all the els in your screenshot there will be tiny gap between the ruler and numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any difference. In both your example and the Google example, the numbers are shorter than the "l"s in "Hello."

Comment: Yeah, I want the digits to be as tall as the "K" in the example... do you know why they are shorter (by 1-2 pixels, but still), unlike the Google Fonts example?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with the font itself - on small font-sizes it appears faulty, but in large font-sizes (such as the default Google Fonts preview size), it appears well.

Very irritating. I wasted too much time on this.

I will open a bug in the [Github repo](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro).